# how to dynamically add buttons with labels from an appconfig in c#

Tags: c#, button

i have 11 buttons that is loading from my appconfig as ff:

```
<appSettings>
<add key="TotalApplications" value="7" />


<add key="Application_Name1" value="App1"/>
<add key="Application1_Executable_Name" value=""/>
<add key="Application1_Executable_Path" value="C:\"/>
<add key="Application1_AutoClose" value="true"/>
<add key="Application1_Icon" value="C:\"/>

<add key="Application_Name2" value="App2"/>
<add key="Application2_Executable_Name" value=""/>
<add key="Application2_Executable_Path" value="C:\Program Files"/>
<add key="Application2_AutoClose" value="true"/>
<add key="Application2_Icon" value="C:\pictures\"/>

<add key="Application_Name3" value="App3"/>
<add key="Application3_Executable_Name" value=""/>
<add key="Application3_Executable_Path" value="C:\"/>
<add key="Application3_AutoClose" value="true"/>
<add key="Application3_Icon" value="C:\picture\"/>
```

this adds up to the 11th button. What i want to do is when a page loads it must show the ff:

```
Menu 1   
  App1        App2      App3      App4   App5

Menu2

  App6        App7      App8      App9   App10

Menu3

  App11
```

what i have tried is this 
                Button button = new Button();

```
            button.Left = (i % 5) * 190;
            button.Top = (i / 6) * 250;
            button.Width = 180;
            button.Height = 190;
            pnlControls.Controls.Add(button)
```

which works but its loading as follows

```
app1 app2 app3 app4 app5
app6 app7 app8 app9 app10
```

how do i get it to dynamically add a label and split the buttons to look as the above requested

Comment: Why don't you use a FlowLayoutPanel? You could use one with horizontal orientation for the row, and for the split of 4 and 3 buttons the vertical inside of it.

Comment: this is not what the web/app.config is for. What about using a database where you put all your controls in? Then you could use EntityFramework to load them dynamically in your application.

Comment: yeah i know,but i have to use it from the app config thats why im not sure how to do it